# How to pass $(".type").val() for a particular row id in $(".type").autocomplete()

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am fetching product type with following code which is working perfectly.
My problem is there are multiple `.type`. I would like to call code for a particular `.type`. Parent div of type is `.row' and each`.row`has unique row id.
I would like to pass $(".type").val()` for perticular `.row` id

How to do this.

```
        $(function() {
            function log(message) {
                $("<div>").text(message).prependTo("#log");
                $("#log").scrollTop(0);
            }

            $(".type").autocomplete({
                source: function(request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "autoProductType",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            str: $(".type").val(),// This value
                            maxRows: 5
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            response($.map(data.productTypeList, function(item) {
                                console.log(item);
                                return {
                                    label: item.productType,
                                    value: item.productType,
                                    id: item.productTypeId
                                };
                            }));
                        },
                        error: function(data) {
                            alert(data.productTypeList);
                            console.log(typeof data);
                            console.log(data);
                            alert('error');
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 1,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    log(ui.item ?
                            "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                            "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
                    var pid = $(this).parents('.row').attr('id');
                    $("#" + pid + " .typeId").val(ui.item.id);
                },
                open: function() {
                    $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
                },
                close: function() {
                    $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**Edit:**  I am trying following but this is also not working

```
 function get_row_dtl() {
            var pid = $(this).parents('.row').attr('id');
            var val = $('#' + pid + ' .type').val();
            return val;
        }
```

at autocomplete

```
str: get_row_dtl(),
```

**Edit:**Please See the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pp8rp/).
Here I am creating autocomplete on type.
My auto complete is working properly for first type(Showing all product type here).
But for 2nd third and next it is not showing all product list It is showing only that has been select in first one. So I want to display all product list(on autocomplete) on 2nd and next type

Comment: Please See this http://jsfiddle.net/Pp8rp/

Comment: So you have to pass to autocomplete the current selected value as __str__ ?

Comment: YeS. Please see the edit on question

Comment: Is not __request.term__ what are you looking for? It stores the current term in the input.

Comment: On second and next types why it is not showing all product list. I think it is passing only first `productTypeId` thats why not showing other product types

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54414/discussion-between-irvin-dominin-aka-edward-and-xrcwrn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Replace `$(".type").val()` with `request.term`.

From http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

**Function:** The third variation, a callback, provides the most flexibility and can be used to connect any data source to Autocomplete. The callback gets two arguments:

- A request object, with a single term property, which refers to the value currently in the text input. For example, if the user enters "new yo" in a city field, the Autocomplete term will equal "new yo".
- A response callback, which expects a single argument: the data to suggest to the user. This data should be filtered based on the provided term, and can be in any of the formats described above for simple local data. It's important when providing a custom source callback to handle errors during the request. You must always call the response callback even if you encounter an error. This ensures that the widget always has the correct state.

Comment: I still think this answer satisfies the original and later requirements. The jsfiddle doesn't run, and relies on a non-existent url, so I can't really edit that usefully. What happens when you try it?

Comment: It was my mistake I havent read it carefully. With your answer I got the result.

Comment: That's nice to know. I was a bit concerned when my answer got downvoted, because I couldn't see what was wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

please change your function get_row_dtl() to

```
function get_row_dtl() {
    var $el= $(':focus');
    var pid = $el.parents('.row').attr('id');
    var val = $('#' + pid + ' .type').val();
    return val;
        }
```

$(':focus'); is used to get the focused element. so any element on which outocomplete is bonded is focused. this will line will give you the reference and you will get the desired result.
I have checked it and its working. please mark it as answer if it works.

Comment: I tried this. But for me it is not giving autocomplete. Thanks for your help I have done this.